# I dynamically add a button, how do I use this button in another void in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I dynamically add a button, for example:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
   ui->setupUi(this);

  QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton(this);
  btn->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred,QSizePolicy::Preferred);
  btn->move(150,150);
  btn->resize(100,100);
  btn->show();

}
```

how do I use this button in another void in Qt??
for example, I want to click another button to delete this dynamically added button.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but take a look at the Qt documentation on Dialog examples, the Extension Example.  This shows how to use a button to set the visibility of other widgets.

Answer (score 0):

your button is defined inside the constructor so after you do

```
btn->resize(100,100);
btn->show();
```

and exit the constructor you has nothing in the hand to manipulate the button (which is what you need now)

one way to solve this is to declare the button as a class member and then you can use its name to change it as much as you need.

edit:

the header:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>

namespace Ui
{
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QPushButton *myButton{nullptr};
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

the cpp:

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    myButton = new QPushButton("some button");
    myButton->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred,QSizePolicy::Preferred);
    myButton->move(150,150);
    myButton->resize(100,100);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    delete myButton;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
      myButton->show();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    // close or do what ever you want with it
    myButton->close();
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to declare the button as a class member? I don't know how to do this.  Besides, I wonder that the button belongs to the mainwindow class, why can't use mainwindow to do this?